# Chrome extension won't allow get request

Tags: google-chrome-extension, get

I'm trying to create my first chrome extension. Basically I have a simple html page and some javascript that im using to allow users to enter some data, the script will format it correctly and then output it:

```
<form>
    MAC ADDRESS: <input type="text" id="mac" name="macAddress" maxlength="17" >

    <button onclick="convert(); return false;">Convert</button>

    </form>
```

Javascript:

```
function convert() {

        var mac = document.getElementById('mac').value; //get string
        var mac2 = mac.replace(/\:|-/g,""); //remove colons and dashes


        //
        //add fullstops after every 4th character, appart from last character. 
        //

        mac2 = mac2.replace(/(.{4})(?!$)/g , '$1.');


        //output string
        document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML= mac2;


};
```

My problem is that while this works fine as a normal web page, the get method, to the same page, is not working when I tried to implement it as an extension.

I've followed the tutorials on google's site and the extension is showing up but it doesn't seem to be able to handle get requests. I've tried modifying the manifest file using different suggestions I found on here but still no success.

Theres nothing in the console when I try to debug it (something briefly flickers up when I submit the get request but it doesn't stay up long enough to see what the issue is).

I'd really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction with this!

Comment: Since you don't want to submit the form, why do you specify a `method` in the first place ?

Comment: oops, I hadn't originally but I was trying all sorts of stupid things to see if it would make a difference!

Answer (score 1):

Due to the **[Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)** applied to extensions:

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both inline  blocks and inline **event handlers** (e.g. ).
>   [...]
>   The inline event handler definitions must be rewritten in terms of **addEventListener** and extracted into **popup.js**.

For more info atake a look at **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#JSExecution)**.

Comment: I've just tried to implement this and I'm still having no joy - still no errors in the console apart from the one that is flickering up too quickly to read. :(

Comment: Then you need to show us some code, because we can't guess what might be wrong with your code.